# jQuery.attr() and data() always return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to fix this issue I've had.

Essentially I have tried lowercasing all the values and it still didn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="country">
    <option data-code="US" selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
    <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-code="AU" value="Australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#country").change(function () {
    var test = $("#country").data("code")
    alert(test)
})
```

**And:**

```
$("#country").change(function () {
    var test = $("#country").attr("data-code")
    alert(test)
})
```

I always get undefined as the response no matter what I do, as far as I can tell this shouldn't be an issue as the jQuery docs had a similar example that works fine. Chrome dev tools also show no errors so I am honestly stumped!

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no `data-code` attribute in the element you're selecting; the `<option>` elements have them, so: `$('#country option:selected').data('code')` (assuming you want the `data-code` attribute-value from the selected `<option>`, obviously).

Comment: #country exposes no data-code attribute. Only option does. Check your function arguments: console.log(arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the jQuery method `data()` on the selected `option` that have the `data-*` attributes and not directly on the parent element `select`, like:

```js
$('#country').change(function() {
  console.log( $(this).find('option:selected').data('code') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
  <option data-code="US" selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
  <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
  <option data-code="AU" value="Australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```

**NOTE :** I prefer the use of **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** instead of `.attr()` (suggested in the other answer) since it's more efficient in such cases because it made especially for the `data-* attributes`.

Comment: I tried them both because I the other one didn't work. It works now though thank you very much.

Comment: It should.. You're welcome brother... Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#country").change(function () {
        var test = $("#country option:selected").attr("data-code")
        alert(test)
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
    <option data-code="US" selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
    <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-code="AU" value="Australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Use `option:selected` along with the selector to find the option selected.

Answer (score 1):

you are not using the correct selector for the `data-code` attribute. Just because it doesn't stay on `#country` element.

So please modify your jQuery selector as follows:

```js
$("#country").change(function () {
        var test = $("#country option:selected").attr("data-code");
        alert(test);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
    <option data-code="US" selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
    <option data-code="GB" value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option data-code="AU" value="Australia">Australia</option>
</select>
```

at that point also the other way you where trying will work

```
$("#country").change(function () {
        var test = $("#country option:selected").data("code");
        alert(test);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use find to get the option selected, so you don't have to repeat `$("#country")`

```
$("#country").change(function () {
  var test = $(this).find("option:selected").data("code")
  alert(test)
})
```